# IBM Conversation + Facebook

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, messenger

I followed this tutorial: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2016/05/bot-for-facebook-messenger-using-bluemix/

It works like a charm but my app does not recognize entities (like @sys_number) in messenger. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solv my problem with **convResults.entities[0].value**

```
function callWatson(payload, sender) {
    w_conversation.message(payload, function (err, convResults) {

    //Consultar Ticket
    if(convResults.intents[0].intent == 'ajax'){
        if(typeof convResults.entities !== 'undefined' && convResults.entities.length > 0){
          numberTicket = convResults.entities[0].value;
          ticket_id = numberTicket.substr(6,6);
          sendAjax(sender, ticket_id, numberTicket);
        }else {
          messengerSend();
        }

        }


    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying it recognizes them in the tryout panel but not in messenger? that seems odd to me. Go to into your entities, into system entities, and make sure they are all flipped to on.

Comment: That's seems odd for me too, but is exactly what's happen. I can see the response in the 'try out' and not see in messenger

Comment: I just went in and tested on my own facebook bot and everything worked as expected. Please make sure your facebook bot is connected to the same workspace as you are testing in. and also that sys entities are turned on

Comment: Works fine in 'try out'

Comment: ok, even more interesting...it doesnt respond at all? it is likely a problem with facebook messenger displaying one of the characters or something. If it was not understanding the sys-entity it would fall to anything-else or have SOME kind of response no matter what. 
Do you know of any way to check the logs of your facebook app? 

Also, please try doing a nested dialog (ie dialog boxes going to the right) with something other than sys-entity, maybe there is a problem with your app sending context to facebook?